# SQL Query For a List of IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database. This database includes three tables:

**Group**

```
ID (int: primary key)
Name (string)
IsActive (bit)
```

**Product**

```
ID (int: primary key)
Name (string)
Description (string)
PublicID (int)
```

**GroupProductLookup**

```
ID (int: primary key)
PublicID (int)
GroupID (int)
```

I need a query that will return *every* group and the list of public IDs of the products that are in the group. If there are no products, null or an empty set will work. An example would be:

```
| GroupID | Name  | Products  |
|---------|-------|-----------|
| 1       | Alpha | (1, 5, 8) |
| 2       | Beta  | (none)    |
| 3       | Cat   | (2, 7)    |
```

I know how to query the groups. But, I don't know how to get a list of the product ids that belong in the group. This is what I have so far..

```
SELECT
  g.ID as 'GroupID',
  g.Name as 'Name',
FROM
  [Group] g
```

How do I get the products IDs?

Thanks!

Comment: You want Id values as a comma-separated string? Please post sample data to accompany your expected result, [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [How to concatenate from multiple rows into single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like aggregation using `string_agg()` with `left join`:

```
select g.id, g.name, 
       string_agg(gp.publicid, ',') within group (order by gp.publicid)
from groups g left join
     GroupProductLookup gp
     on gp.groupid = g.id
group by g.id, g.name;
```